# Outlook 2013 user agent

Tags: html, internet-explorer, outlook, user-agent

I've been trying to understand the user agent string sent by Outlook 2013 when you set a URL to be a folder home page.

Here's an example with unrelated stuff removed for clarity:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0; Microsoft Outlook 15.0.4420)
```

I was doing some tests with the F12 tools in IE and I can't get it to duplicate the same results. For example, I can get it to send MSIE 7.0, but it doesn't send the Trident/*.0 string at all unless I set it back to IE10 standards mode.

Is this saying that they are using Trident 6 in IE 7 compatibility mode?

Is Outlook just using whatever version of Trident it finds on the machine, or does it have it's own version?

What feature support can I expect from this combination?